# How to join 3 tables using sql server

Tags: mysql

this is the query i tried to join 3 tables but while running a getting error.
please any one fix this problem thanks.

`SELECT category.name,brands.name, products.name, products.price,products.qty
FROM products, category,brands
WHERE  products.ID = products.catid join products.brid;`

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can Join tables with the help of `Join` syntax. Here is how

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
FROM ((Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID);
```